# JavaScriptのテストコードのimportパス指定で"../"を使いたくない

Tags: javascript

現在、gulp + babel + mocha の組み合わせでテストを書こうと考えています。
プロダクションコードはroot/src/modulesディレクトリ配下においています。

テストコードはroot/test/modules下に、プロダクションコードと同じ構成で置きたいです。

この場合、テストコードに

`import sut from '../../../(repeatUntilRoot...)/src/mosules/(pathToSUT...)'`

と書くのが非常に煩雑です。

プロダクションコードのbuildにはWebpackを使用していて

`import someModule from 'modules/path/to/module'`

のように解決できるようにしています。
テスト時にWebpackを用いずに上記プロダクションコードの呼び方と同様の記載で、テストコードからテスト対象モジュールを呼び出すことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 環境変数に設定することで可能、と自己解決しました。

`export NODE_PATH=/path/to/project/root/src`

しかし、この方法だとフォルダ移動した時に変更が必要なこと、チーム開発で全員がやる必要があるときのわずらわしさがありますね。

他の方法でnpmにディレクトリを読ませる方法を引き続き募集します。

Comment: さらに自己解決  
https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520  
http://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20150101

Comment: この質問が「回答済み」として表示されるのに、回答欄に自分の選んだ解決方法をコピーして投稿する必要がありますが、そうすれば他のユーザーの検索結果に出ますので、お勧めします。

Answer (score 1):

環境変数に設定することで可能、と自己解決しました。 export NODE_PATH=/path/to/project/root/src

Answer (score 0):

[wavy](https://github.com/kolodny/wavy#readme)を使用してみるのはどうでしょうか？`package.json`の位置が`~`として扱われます。

```
mkdir foo && cd foo
echo 'module.exports="foo"' > index.js

npm install wavy
node -e "console.log(require('~/index.js'))"
# foo
```